# Collect Username/Password via UIAlertView for NTLM challenge in a UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ntlm

I have a UIWebview that redirects the user to a secure page which returns a NTLM challenge. I am trying to implement a UIAlertView that gets launched in a blocking mode inside willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge delegate call. I am planning on asking the user to provide its credentials in the UIAlertView and then use them to answer NSURLAuthenticationChallenge. First of all I see that the UIAlertView is not modal. If it was then I assume everything would work. But now that it does not, are there any other solutions around it?

Comment: https://github.com/Darktt/DTAlertView

Comment: This does not provide a BLOCKING/MODAL alert view. The code after [alert show] keeps executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably got this concept of blocking modal dialog from desktop app programming. It's possible there, because the keyboard and mouse have their distinct event sources. On iOS though, almost all events are routed through the main thread event loop. Most importantly, GUI rendering and touch events. So if a blocking modal dialog was possible, displaying it would have stopped the main thread event loop and the application would stall. Touch events would not get picked up. Therefore, **blocking modal dialog is not possible in iOS by design**. The same applies to Android.

So get used to asynchronous programming. You don't block the execution, ever. You implement delegates, write callback handlers and event listeners. In this particular case, implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` and call methods of `[challenge sender]` delegate when user clicks a button. The authenticating `NSURLConnection` does not continue until you do that.

Or use `UIAlertController`, it's preferred over `UIAlertView` since iOS8 and things are way simpler with handler blocks. Understanding of blocks (or closures in general) is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: I did something similar. I ended up saving the challenge URL and when user clicked "okay", I re-executed the challenge URL and and when the challenge came along again, I provided the credentials saved via alert view. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to re-execute anything. `NSURLConnection` is on hold until you call some of the `[challenge sender]` method. Which means that the first challenge you "thrown away" is hanging on the server and inside iOS. It will get timed out and cleared later, sure. But if i was a server, i would not like a client creating a zombie connection for each authentication.

Comment: creating UIAlertView inside willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge does not block the method from executing. It ends up returning the method, webview showing an error and THEN alert popping up. Do you have a working example as a proof? Maybe I was missing something in my earlier implementation.